# Java использование видео памяти для хранения данных

Tags: java, javafx

как в java использовать память видеокарты для хранения переменных (а конкретно классов)?

Comment: задайте его более развернуто. использовать для чего?

Answer (score 1):

Никак. JVM создает объекты в heap (куча). Без специально написанной библиотеки (на си) видео память не доступна для хранения объектов.

Comment: а можешь посоветовать библиотеку?

Comment: скорей всего библиотеку вам прийдется писать самому. на мой взгляд в вашем вопросе мало смысла.